Highcharts pie/donut chart tooltip on outer circle of chart
I want to attain pie/donut chart tooltip similar to google charts (this) tooltip. I am using highcharts-react-official and the tooltip should show outside the outer circle. Tooltip is quite big and is scrollable based on data, when I hover onto the lower part of the chart, it hides the entire chart and blocks the user to hover onto the other parts of the graph
Below is the code, tried positioner function with different position but unable to attain what needs to be attained on different resolutions
chart: {
  zooming: {
    mouseWheel: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  height: '210px',
  spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  },
  legend: {
    itemStyle: {
      fontSize: '12px'
    },
    layout: stats?.allocated_space_credits?.length < 5 ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal',
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    borderWidth: 0,
    width: 280,
    itemWidth: 140,
    itemMarginBottom: 13
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  credits: false,
  colors: stats?.allocated_space_credits?.map(item => item?.space?.color),
  tooltip: {
    padding: 0,
    borderRadius: 4,
    followPointer: false,
    outside: true,
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function(tooltip) {
      let goal = stats?.allocated_space_credits.find(item => item?.space?.name == this?.point?.name);
      return `<div class="chart-tooltip">
        <div class="head">${this.point.name}</div>
        <div class="body">
          <div class="content-row">
            <div class="title">Credit allocated: </div>
            <div class="count">${this.point.y}</div>
          </div>
          ${ goal?.space?.space_goals?.length ? `<div class="content-row">
              <div class="title">Goal: </div>
              <div class="tag-wrapper">
                ${goal?.space?.space_goals?.map((item, idx) => `<span class="custom-tag">${item?.['name']}</span>`)}
              </div>
          </div>` : '' }
        </div>
      </div>
      `
    },
    positioner: function(labelWidth, _, point) {
      return {
        x: point.plotX,
        y: point.plotY
      };
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      showInLegend: true,
      borderWidth: 2,
      fillColor: '#ECEDF0',
      borderRadius: 1,
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false,
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: "pie",
      innerSize: "62%",
      data: stats?.allocated_space_credits?.map(item => ({ name: item?.space?.name, y: item?.allocated_credits})),
      states: {
        inactive: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
    }
  ],
  accessibility: {
    enabled: false
  }
}

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Unfortunately your link doesn't work. Could you please tell us more what the tooltip should look like? And how you want to change its position. Please elaborate on what the problem is so I could help you.

@DominikChudy , updated th link, you can now take the reference of the tooltip, how it should look like

Thanks! So basically you want to show the tooltip outside the chart? You can do it by manipulating x and y coordinates in the tooltip.positioner function for example like that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wdelkz?file=index.js but please let me know if we're moving towards the right direction!

Thanks @DominikChudy, yes we are moving in the right direction, but we need to keep followPointer to false and stickOnContact to true so that we can hover and scroll the tooltip and we are showing the legends to the left of the pie chart but  the tooltip is not perfectly aligned to the outer circle

Sure thing, then I suggest to work a bit on the positioner function code. I'd calculate the x and y coordinates using point angle and trigonometric functions. A demo for you: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qcteym5L/

This might help you https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/pie-basic

I upvoted the question because showing tooltip outside pie chart should be basic functionality and it seems for the past 10+ years Highcharts still doesn't support it without hacks.
However, for your particular problem, you say that "tooltip is large and scrollable". Have you considered showing the tooltip at a static position outside the pie-chart? And using mouseover events to toggle its contents.

Thanks @pkExec for upvoting the question, but showing the tooltip at static position is not required by the product.  Dominik demo helped a bit but still not attained it fully.
